# Why do we add const in custom comparator function that are used in sort()?

Tags: c++, constants, comparator

We do not change the value of the variables in the comparator function only compare or read it. So what is the need of adding `const` in the comparator?
Is it a good programming habit or there is some other reason?

Comment: Your first sentence is *exactly* the reason why a member comparator is `const`. The const-ness enforces your "do not" to be "cannot", which is critical . Thou shalt not modify a sequence whilst being mangled by canned `sort`; that's the job for `sort`; not you.

Comment: Yeah, it answers them, Paul. Thank you, guys.